# How to downgrade the Kernel on 11.10

Tags: 11.10, kernel

Because of the high power usage I'd like to downgrade my kernel in Ubuntu 11.10 to the version used in 10.10 or 11.04. How can I do that and won't it cause any problems?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/233380/how-do-i-downgrade-kernel-on-12-10

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**How can I do...**

You could download the kernel binaries from the old or new Ubuntu releases /1/.

Ubuntu Packages Search: http://packages.ubuntu.com

Picking natty-updates kernel linux-image-2.6.38-10-generic : http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty-updates/linux-image

Downloading it and installing with the command:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-image-2.6.38-10-generic_2.6.38-10.46_i386.deb
```

Package management is telling:

```
Selecting previously deselected package linux-image-2.6.38-10-generic.
(Reading database ... 127436 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking linux-image-2.6.38-10-generic (from linux-image-2.6.38-10-generic_2.6.38-10.46_i386.deb) ...
Done.
Setting up linux-image-2.6.38-10-generic (2.6.38-10.46) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 2.6.38-10-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-10-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-10-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 2.6.38-10-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-10-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 2.6.38-10-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-10-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 2.6.38-10-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-10-generic
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found background image: /lib/plymouth/themes/my-plymouth/my-wallpaper.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-12-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-12-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-10-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-10-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Microsoft Windows XP Professional on /dev/sda1
Found Ubuntu 10.10 (10.10) on /dev/sdd1
done
```

Rebooting

Picking from the grub > Previous Linux versions > Kernel 2.6.38-10

...and the (K)Ubuntu is telling that i'm running with the 2.6.38-10-generic /2/.

[image]

**...won't it cause any problems?**

Well ;) you could tell us...

**Links**

1. http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?51992-FAQ-Kernel
2. http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?53976-FAQ-Version-info-Regenerated

Comment: Thanks, the lucid kernel killed my wifi, but the natty one works just fine.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've downgraded and the horrible regression bug that bit me in Oneiric is gone with no apparent side effects. +1

Comment: I have downgraded it to 2.6.38 as well. Working almost fine. And battery life increased by atleast 50 mins. So I shall use this kernel whenever I need more battery power :) Thanks for the post.

Comment: might wanna add you need linux-headers for dkms so be sure to install them before the image..