# Install older kernel version

Tags: installation, drivers, 13.04, kernel

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 and the kernel version is 3.8.0.

Unfortunately, I need a [driver](http://www.exar.com/connectivity/uart-and-bridging-solutions/usb-uarts/xr21v1410) which cannot be compiled and installed in 3.8.0.

As a result, I want to install older version(2.6.35) and I want to switch between them when I need to use the driver.

Is it possible? How to do so?

Comment: You would be better off trying to figure out how to compile the driver with a current **supported** version than installing such an old version of the kernel.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the answers to this question, it may provide some pointers:
[How do I install an older 2.6.37 Kernel Version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91372/how-do-i-install-an-older-2-6-37-kernel-version?rq=1)

As far as I can work out, if you go into the Grub menu at start up, just after the BIOS screen, you then have a number of options for booting.

**If your Grub menu does not show when you boot up**, then the simplest way to display your Grub is to press and hold the SHIFT button while booting.

As an alternative, you can always displays Grub without it booting any particular kernel:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

change `grub_timeout` to -1

finish off by running

```
sudo update-grub
```