# Does anybody know how I might fix this error? (Mainly how to fix broken packages in linux)

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
 python-rpy2 : Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.1.2) but 3.0.2-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: 3.0.2-1ubuntu1 is to be installed indicates that you are using Ubuntu 14.04 and  python-rpy2 depends on r-base-core 3.0.2-1ubuntu1 by default in Ubuntu 14.04, so you are probably trying to install or have installed a package that you're not supposed to install. That's why you got a "broken packages" error message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the 3.0.2-1ubuntu1 kernel, compile it, update-grub and reboot :

some examples here :

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1758823

[How do I install an older 2.6.37 Kernel Version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91372/how-do-i-install-an-older-2-6-37-kernel-version)

Comment: I tried using the links to help but I'm still not entirely sure how to download the newer kernel :/

Comment: 3.0.2-1ubuntu1 is not the version of the kernel. It is the version of the r-base-core package in the default Ubuntu 14.04 repositories.