# How do I install an old kernel?

Tags: apt, kernel

I am running an instance of Ubuntu 15.10. I need to install the latest kernel used by Ubuntu 14.10, which I think is 3.16.0-28-generic. Entering `sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.16.0-28-generic` returns an error message stating that it's not available and may have been obsoleted or whatever. I think if I add something to `sources.list` it will be able to get it. But what do I add to it?

And before anyone goes on about the troubles this may produce, it doesn't matter to me.

Answer (score 29):

In Ubuntu, use browser to navigate to > [http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/)
Scroll to the bottom of the list; choose your kernel. Download the following files (xxxxxx will be replaced with numbers indicating the kernel version. Assuming you have a 64bit OS):

> linux-headers-xxxxxx-generic-xxxxxx_amd64.deb
>
> linux-headers-xxxxxx_all.deb
>
> linux-image-xxxxxx-generic-xxxxxx_amd64.deb

Move all these files to a folder.
cd into it.
Install all these packages by running

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Choose new kernel from grub menu.

**Update**: Since its an ubuntu instance you can manually get the links and and use wget to download the packages

Comment: What is meant by choose new kernel from grub menu?

Comment: I wrote this answer thinking of a ubuntu desktop, in which u will get each entry for each kernel, for a server instance, u can just restart the server then it will boot automatically to latest kernel.. Or u can edit the config for a specific kernel

Comment: @Sijin Krishnan Should we manually edit grub menu before reboot to "choose new kernel from grub menu"?

Comment: The grub will boot with the latest version of kernel from the  installed ones by default.. you only need to touch the config, if you want to boot with any other lower version s...

Comment: You will also need to download linux-modules-version_amd64.deb and the order of installation requires that the modules be installed before the kernel image. [Tony George manages a private ppa](https://code.launchpad.net/~teejee2008/ukuu-github/+git/ukuu-github) which releases a Ubuntu Kernel Update Utility (ukuu) which looks promising though I was unable to install it on 18.04.2 today. It seems to have been released for other Ubuntu versions and I may attempt to fix the packaging for 18.04.2 on launchpad.

Answer (score 8):

If you know the exact version you want, e.g. 5.4.0-26-generic, just run

```
sudo apt install linux-image-5.4.0-26-generic
```

The dependencies will be installed automatically. Then in the next boot, select it in the grub menu.

Comment: For me this installed (in my case) the `linux-modules-5.19.0-32-generic` package too but I 'felt' something in missing (as i usually remove 3 packages when 'uninstalling' a kernel). System booted indeed but Xorg/gnome was not running, just tty. I also needed to run `sudo apt install linux-modules-extra--yourversion-generic` for gnome to work.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the official Ubuntu stock kernel (not a mainline kernel) from an unsupported version, see below.

For differences between Mainline and Stock kernels see https://askubuntu.com/a/91374/555474

I had to install an even older kernel (2.6.32.21-generic) for stock modules to work with a custom kernel. No hardware was working, so I had to download manually.

Here is how to obtain the discontinued kernels manually from http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/

Essentially you will need the kernel's headers for your processor, common (all) headers, and the kernel image for your processor.

1. In the steps below, replace `x.x.xx-xx` with your kernel version and `amd64` with your processor type. Note this is for the generic kernel and not using extra features such as PAE.
2. Go to http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/ (I believe this lists most if not all the old kernel packages)
3. In the page CTRL+F find `headers-x.x.xx-xx-generic` and download the

   1. linux-headers-x.x.xx-xx-generic_x.x.xx-xx.yy_**amd64**.deb
   2. linux-headers-x.x.xx-xx-generic_x.x.xx-xx.yy_**all**.deb
4. In the page CTRL+F find `image-x.x.xx-xx-generic` and download the

   1. linux-image-2.6.32-21-generic_2.6.32-21.32_**amd64**.deb
5. Put all of these packages in a folder alone, and from that folder (`cd` into it) run

   1. `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to install Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer.
In terminal type the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cappelikan/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mainline
```

see screenshot:
[image]. 
It is Gui-based and very easy to use to add and remove mainline (hence the name) kernels.

Comment: If I type `mainline` at the command line, no GUI appears.

Comment: @david.perez try searching in activities bar, you will find it.

Comment: @david.perez, did you install the program? Then you can open it through the application launcher.

Comment: it is a console app with no GUI, and I can only select very recent kernels.  It is usable.