# Can I update to Ubuntu 18.04 from 16.04.4 without kernel update

Tags: upgrade, kernel, 18.04

Can I update to Ubuntu 18.04 from 16.04.4 without updating kernel version because of my wifi coova and Acer E5 laptop?

Comment: Maybe this link can help you: [Ubuntu Development version / How to participate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018033/ubuntu-development-version-how-to-participate). In general, the upgrade to the next LTS version is recommended (and suggested automatically), after the first point release (in July or August).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install an old kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/700214/how-do-i-install-an-old-kernel)

Comment: Why do you assume that everything that comes with the 18.04 release will work with an old kernel?

Comment: Do you *know* that your wifi does not work in Bionic (18.04 LTS)? Or are you only fearing that there will be problems? You can try Ubuntu live to check, or if you need a proprietary wifi driver, you can create an installed system in a USB pendrive and test it 'all the way'. See [Try Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) before installing it](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389) and [Boot Ubuntu from external drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786986/boot-ubuntu-from-external-drive/942312#942312)