# After last 14.04 package upgrade PC was slow, soundless and without brightness adjust (Inspiron - 5552)

Tags: 14.04, drivers, upgrade, dell, inspiron

After last (day 22 of this month) package upgrade of ubuntu 14.04, my PC got slow (compiz using too much cpu), soundless and i can't adjust brightness anymore. When i reinstall factory system (ubuntu 14.04) it becomes normal. However, once i upgrade packages, the same problem occur.
PC configurations:

[image]

There is any way to fix this without having to upgrade the ubuntu version, and keep packages updated as possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using an older kernel?  (ie. at grub, selecting advanced & then picking an older kernel)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an older kernel, which will not affect your packages. See [How do I install an old kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/700214/how-do-i-install-an-old-kernel)