# Why are keyboard + mouse not responding after being suspended, Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04, suspend, mac

My iMac (from 2009) is not responding to cues to wake up from suspend: it needs rebooting each time. This comes after updating following 7 months without being used, and soon after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04.

The system details are:

```
Kernel: 5.19.0-35-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: GNOME 42.5
    Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: Apple product: iMac9,1 v: 1.0
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: Apple model: Mac-F2218EA9 serial: <superuser required> UEFI: Apple
    v: IM91.88Z.008D.B08.0904271717 date: 04/27/09
CPU:
  Info: dual core model: Intel Core2 Duo E8135 bits: 64 type: MCP
    arch: Core Yorkfield rev: A cache: L1: 128 KiB L2: 6 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 1596 min/max: 1596/2660 cores: 1: 1596 2: 1596
    bogomips: 10613
  Flags: ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA C79 [GeForce 9400] vendor: Apple iMac 9 1 driver: nouveau
    v: kernel bus-ID: 03:00.0
  Device-2: Apple Built-in iSight type: USB driver: uvcvideo bus-ID: 1-4:3
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 1.22.1.1 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.1
    compositor: gnome-shell driver: gpu: nouveau resolution: 1680x1050~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: NVAC v: 3.3 Mesa 22.2.5 direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: NVIDIA MCP79 High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
    v: kernel bus-ID: 00:08.0
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.0-35-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: NVIDIA MCP79 Ethernet driver: forcedeth v: kernel port: 21e0
    bus-ID: 00:0a.0
  IF: enp0s10 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Broadcom BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN
    vendor: Apple AirPort Extreme driver: b43-pci-bridge v: N/A bus-ID: 04:00.0
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Apple Built-in Bluetooth 2.0+EDR HCI type: USB driver: btusb
    v: 0.8 bus-ID: 4-1.1:3
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: up address: <filter>
    bt-v: 1.2 lmp-v: 2.1
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 1.2 TiB used: 54.1 GiB (4.4%)
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Western Digital model: WD3200AAJS-40H3A0
    size: 298.09 GiB
  ID-2: /dev/sdb type: USB vendor: Seagate model: Expansion HDD
    size: 931.51 GiB
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 291.86 GiB used: 33.23 GiB (11.4%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 511 MiB used: 6.1 MiB (1.2%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/sda1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 4.07 GiB used: 6.8 MiB (0.2%) file: /swapfile
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 43.0 C mobo: N/A gpu: nouveau temp: 69.0 C
  Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 1198
Info:
  Processes: 225 Uptime: 11m Memory: 3.58 GiB used: 2.02 GiB (56.4%)
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: N/A Packages: 1663 Shell: Bash
  v: 5.1.16 inxi: 3.3.13
```

dmesg output:

```
sudo dmesg --level=err,warn

[    1.927416] device-mapper: core: CONFIG_IMA_DISABLE_HTABLE is disabled. Duplicate IMA measurements will not be recorded in the IMA log.
[    1.927655] platform eisa.0: EISA: Cannot allocate resource for mainboard
[    1.927659] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 1
[    1.927662] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 2
[    1.927666] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 3
[    1.927669] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 4
[    1.927672] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 5
[    1.927675] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 6
[    1.927678] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 7
[    1.927681] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 8
[    2.243441] clocksource: timekeeping watchdog on CPU1: Marking clocksource 'tsc' as unstable because the skew is too large:
[    2.243446] clocksource:                       'hpet' wd_nsec: 31048240560 wd_now: 30914284 wd_last: 24d4bc6 mask: ffffffff
[    2.243451] clocksource:                       'tsc' cs_nsec: 511983988 cs_now: 1441a93cce cs_last: 13f0b0b46e mask: ffffffffffffffff
[    2.243455] clocksource:                       'tsc' is current clocksource.
[    2.271464] clocksource: Checking clocksource tsc synchronization from CPU 1 to CPUs 0.
[    2.550720] Unstable clock detected, switching default tracing clock to "global"
               If you want to keep using the local clock, then add:
                 "trace_clock=local"
               on the kernel command line
[    3.577767] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of preferred minimum block size (4096 bytes)
[   18.378948] systemd-journald[269]: File /var/log/journal/9bd16b030daa432aa3dd9e037ea68a06/system.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
[   23.182410] applesmc applesmc.768: hwmon_device_register() is deprecated. Please convert the driver to use hwmon_device_register_with_info().
[   23.369700] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43/ucode16_mimo.fw failed with error -2
[   23.369761] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43/ucode16_mimo.fw failed with error -2
[   23.369995] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43-open/ucode16_mimo.fw failed with error -2
[   23.370049] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43-open/ucode16_mimo.fw failed with error -2
[   23.370056] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43/ucode16_mimo.fw" not found
[   23.370093] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43-open/ucode16_mimo.fw" not found
[   23.370117] b43-phy0 ERROR: You must go to https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware and download the correct firmware for this driver version. Please carefully read all instructions on this website.
[   25.186110] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.IXVE.IGPU._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20220331/nsarguments-61)
[   43.332168] kauditd_printk_skb: 54 callbacks suppressed
[   93.350799] systemd-journald[269]: File /var/log/journal/9bd16b030daa432aa3dd9e037ea68a06/user-1000.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
[  230.645609] nouveau 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nvac_fuc084 failed with error -2
[  230.645649] nouveau 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nvac_fuc084d failed with error -2
[  230.645653] nouveau 0000:03:00.0: msvld: unable to load firmware data
[  230.645658] nouveau 0000:03:00.0: msvld: init failed, -19
```

I have been getting lost looking at problems with the nVidia driver. Before updating the kernel I was using a PPA for the driver:
[https://launchpad.net/~kelebek333/+archive/ubuntu/nvidia-legacy](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekelebek333/+archive/ubuntu/nvidia-legacy)

This is apparently not supported for the new kernel:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-340/+bug/1916640

Do I revert to an earlier kernel? If so, how (I am a novice, and also rusty)?

Do I go ahead to a newer kernel, not yet supported?
https://github.com/MeowIce/nvidia-legacy/tree/340.108

Or perhaps there is a way to work around it with changes to brightness controls, which is discussed in forums?

**Update**

This seems to have been solved, by installing an earlier kernel which works with the nvidia driver PPA. Still interested to hear other solutions/advice. For other novices I will list the steps I took and links which I found helpful:

1. Check PPA bug post about latest version of kernel for which driver works: 5.17.x
   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-340/+bug/1916640
2. Download kernel files
   [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.17.15/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.17.15/)
3. Install kernel `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`
   https://askubuntu.com/a/700221/1143711
4. Check GRUB menu:
   `sudo grub-mkconfig | grep -iE "menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux" | awk '{print i++ " : "$1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7}'`
   Old kernel is shown on menu.
5. Follow the instructions of Yuri Sucupira ('long answer') to change grub settings. This allows access to the grub menu on the Mac:
   https://askubuntu.com/a/1299955/1143711
6. Reboot. Select Advanced option from menu, then select kernel 5.17 from menu.
7. Install PPA for nvidia-legacy driver
   `sudo apt install xorg-modulepath-fix`