# How do I downgrade kernel on 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, kernel, downgrade

I did a fresh installation of Ubuntun 12.10 (kernel v3.5.0.21-generic, 64 bit, US English) on my computer after downloading the ISO from Ubuntu.com.

In order for one of my installed programs to work, I would like to downgrade the current kernel version to 3.2.0.24-generic

Questions:

1. Is it advisable to downgrade the current kernet version to an older one?
2. If the answer to (1) above is yes, how do I do it?

As always, detailed instructions on how to issue specific commands at the terminal window are welcome. I am new to Linux and Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why don't you do a fresh install with Ubuntu 12.04?
It comes with kernel 3.2.0-23-generic i think.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/71139/44179

Comment: @ ThiagoPonte: Thanks for the suggestion. Where is the official mirror to download Ubuntu 12.04 with kernel version 3.2.0.24?

Comment: @ iSeth: Thanks for the link. I surfed to packages.ubuntu.com/precise/kernel and couldn't help noticing there are two kernels: linux-image-3.2.0.24-generic and linux-image-3.2.0.24-generic-pae. Could someone help explain the difference between the two please?

Comment: Check [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1908515) link out.

Comment: @ iSeth: Thanks for the link. I see the differences between "generic" and "generic-pae" now. OK, my installed Ubuntu is 64-bit and I suppose the kernel version 3.5.0.21-generic is 64-bit as well, am I right? According to the link: packages.ubuntu.com/precise/kernel, the linux images of 3.2.0.24 are not listed as whether 32-bit or 64-bit. My question is: how do I install the 64-bit version of 3.2.0.24-generic? As always, thanks in advance.

Comment: @ iSeth: Oops, please ignore by latest post asking about the location of the 64 bit version of kernel 3.2.0.24. I've managed to locate it. It's nested within a sub-directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Today I needed to downgrade from 3.5.0-24 to 3.5.0-23 (I have both installed). I succeded with the following:

```
sudo /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.5.0-23-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-23-generic
```

You can find out Your current kernel with:

```
uname -a
```

You can find out other kernels installed on Your computer with::

```
dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d'
```

Mind that You might also need to lock the version of the kernel -- so to prevent it automatic update.

Comment: Please avoid posting the same answer in [more than one place](http://askubuntu.com/a/254219). When tempted to do so, typically: (1) the answer should be customized to account for what is different about the different questions, (2) one question should be flagged for closure as a duplicate of another question (you can flag posts with [15 reputation](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/flag-posts)), (3) the answer should really be a comment, **or** (4) the answer should be posted in the most appropriate place, and one-line comments posted on the other questions summarizing and linking to it.

Comment: Since your system is 12.10 (or at least is using 12.10 kernels), I'd suggest keeping the answer here, removing the other one, and posting a comment on the other question linking here.

Comment: the command is uncorrect, since now kernel is at 3.11 version and it's not spotted by your regexp

Comment: @garakkio: gives `linux-headers-3.11.0-12
linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic
linux-headers-3.11.0-7
linux-headers-3.11.0-7-generic
linux-libc-dev:amd64` to me.

Comment: my bad: didn't spot "other" in "other kernels". Sorry