# what is the right way to downgrade kernel

Tags: apt, kernel, downgrade

I decide to downgrade kernel version due to unsolvable problem with wifi. Ubuntu version is **12.10**, kernel version is **3.5**.

In http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/kernel/ I found the previous kernel version **3.2**.  I decided to install linux-image-3.2.0-51-generic. The question is it enough to install just  *linux-image* package, do I need to install  *linux-header* package too, are there more package I should install?

The second question, as it suggested on the website, the right way to install the packages is to edit the file */etc/apt/sources.list* insert the line *deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main*. However after inserting and running the update I still cannot find packages of *linux-image 3.2* by **apt-cache search linux-images***. Where I am wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to downgrade the Kernel on 11.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/71139/how-to-downgrade-the-kernel-on-11-10)

Comment: @amc, thank you for the comment, the main question what the *image-header* package for, and should I install it? And how to make the downgrade from repository? I don't find answers on these question in the question your mentioned.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> I still cannot find packages of linux-image 3.2 by apt-cache search
>   linux-images*. Where I am wrong?

On spelling. The correct command is

```
apt-cache policy linux-image-*
```

Also, the Tab Completion feature is very handy and you should learn to use it. Open a terminal and write

```
 sudo apt-get install linux-image-
```

Then hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> key twice and read the list, can you see 3.2 kernel ?

> do I need to install linux-header package too, are there more package
>   I should install?

Every linux-image has its own linux-headers version, so it is preferable to install them too.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-
```

and use the same Tab Completion feature (as in linux-image- above) to locate the appropriate ones.