# unmet dependencies for linux-image-extra-virtual

Tags: 14.04, kernel, docker

I am trying to install the `linux-image-extra-*` packages, (which are a prerequisite for Docker) following the instructions [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/#/prerequisites-by-ubuntu-version).

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r) linux-image-extra-virtual
```

But i get the following error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-image-extra-3.19.0-32-generic is already the newest version.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-virtual : Depends: linux-image-generic (= 3.13.0.107.115) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried fixing any broken dependencies using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 152 not to upgrade.
```

And then ran the command to install the linux-image-extra-* kernel packages, but i still get the same error.

I tried `sudo apt-get update` followed by the command to install the linux-image-extra-* kernel packages, but the same thing still.

What could the issue be? And how do i resolve it?

## My system:

Ubuntu 14.04

The output of `uname -r` is:

```
3.19.0-32-generic
```

The output of `dpkg --list | egrep -i --color 'linux-image|linux-headers'` is

```
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-32                     3.19.0-32.37~14.04.1                                all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.19.0
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-32-generic             3.19.0-32.37~14.04.1                                amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.19.0-32-generic               3.19.0-32.37~14.04.1                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-32-generic         3.19.0-32.37~14.04.1                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

## Similar but not actually related posts

- [This one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/719481/cant-install-anything-anymore-unmet-dependencies-for-linux-image) had similar errors, but was an issue with too many items in boot partition, which doesn't appear to be the case for me.

## Potential Solutions?

- I came accross [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/183625/640905) which might be worth a try? It involves removing any lines of code related to the relevant package from the `dpkg status` file. But I am worried that removing kernel image information  from this file might break my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `--fix-broken`/`-f` command to satisfy dependencies, you can try download and install the mentioned dependencies (`linux-image-generic=3.13.0.107.115`):

32 Bit: [Download Link](http://ppa.launchpad.net/canonical-kernel-team/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-meta/linux-image-generic_3.13.0.107.115_i386.deb)

64 Bit: [Download Link](http://ppa.launchpad.net/canonical-kernel-team/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-meta/linux-image-generic_3.13.0.107.115_amd64.deb)

To install the `.deb` file, I recommend you to use [gdebi package installer](https://launchpad.net/gdebi) which also check the package dependencies and tell whether it's satisfied or not:

```
sudo apt install gdebi
sudo gdebi Downloads/linux-image-generic_3.13.0.107.115_arch.deb
```

Replace **arch** with i386 (for 32 bit) or amd64 (for 64 bit).

Comment: Ohh, Brilliant !! :) Thank you so much, that did the trick.  Instead of downloading those deb links, i forced a specific version on apt-get using sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic=3.13.0.107.115  But thank you so much for pointing this out and for going to the extra effort of finding those links.

Comment: Glad it helped !

Answer (score 1):

There may be something wrong. Your kernel  was `3.19.0-32-generic` based on `uname -r` output. But Ubuntu 14.04 latest kernel found on this [link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/linux-generic) was `3.13.0.107.115`. That mean your kernel is ahead of the `trusty` repository source.

So, you may need to check repository list on `/etc/apt/sources.list` or you have installed `3.19.0-32 kernel` manually.

### Option 1

Please try with following command.

```
sudo apt install linux-image-generic-lts-vivid linux-image-extra-virtual-lts-vivid
```

This may update your kernel to `3.19.0.79`.

### Option 2

You can try to roll back your kernel to `3.13.0.107`. But this may need to take care. It is risky. If you agree you can reference this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/331538/what-is-the-right-way-to-downgrade-kernel). And then install again with

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r) linux-image-extra-virtual
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following command.

```
kern_extras="linux-image-extra-virtual linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)"
```

Comment: Welcome to the site and thank you for adding the answer, that you have. Please consider editing your answer to include more details such as what it does, how it will help and the expected outcome.