# I recently freshly installed kubuntu 22.04 via bootable usb and I keep getting these errors ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbols

Tags: kubuntu, live-usb, 22.04, bios, acpi

```
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_PR.PROO._CPC],

AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)

[ 2.808845] (AE_NOT_FOUND)

ACPI Error: Aborting method PR. PRO1. CPC due to previous error (20210730/psparse-529)

[ 2.809087] AE_NOT_FOUND

ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.PRO0._CPC),

(20210730/psargs-330)

[ 2.809107]

ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR. PR02. CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)

[ 2.809238] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_PR.PROO._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)

[ 2.809256] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR. PR03. CPC due to previous error

(AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529) [ 2.834033] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_PACKAGE LIMIT, Index (0x000000005) is beyond end of object (length 0x5) (20210730/exoparg2-393)

[ 2.834091] ACPI Error: Aborting method _TZ.GETP due to previous error (AE_A

ML_PACKAGE LIMIT) (20210730/psparse-529)

[ 2.834105] ACPI Error: Aborting method _TZ.CHGZ. CRT due to previous error (AE AML PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20210730/psparse-529) [ 2.835083] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_PACKAGE LIMIT, Index (0x000000005)

is beyond end of object (length 0x5) (20210730/exoparg2-393) [ 2.835132] ACPI Error: Aborting method _TZ.GETP due to previous error (AE_A

ML PACKAGE LIMIT) (20210730/psparse-529) 2.835145] ACPI Error: Aborting method _TZ.CHGZ. CRT due to previous error (AE AHL PACKAGE LIMIT) (20210730/psparse-529)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)

Comment: @karel I do think it has to do with the latest kernel update…I did try to downgrade to version 20.04 using the usb boot and not setting up wifi in the process, it installed perfectly and all the errors were gone….it was on kernel 5.13

Comment: That's what the last paragraph of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1333162/) says.

Comment: @karel thanks for your reply, if I may ask, how do I downgrade my kernel version thanks

Comment: [what is the right way to downgrade kernel](https://askubuntu.com/q/331538/)