# Lost wireless connectivity after installing older kernel

Tags: 14.04, kernel, intel-wireless

I've successfully reinstalled the 3.13.0-27-generic kernel but now I don't have wireless connectivity. I know I did the last time I booted up with that kernel. HELP!?

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: Link: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7713664/

Comment: How did you  reinstall the kernel? do you have a link? instructions? please post them by editing question and adding them.

Comment: Followed the directions here:

Comment: Followed the directions here:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/71139/how-to-downgrade-the-kernel-on-11-10
I went to http://packages.ubuntu.com/ and clicked on the link for "trusty" which took me to http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/
From there I clicked on "kernels" which took me to http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/kernel/
From there I clicked on the link for linux-image-extra-3.13.0-27-generic which took me to http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/kernel/linux-image-extra-3.13.0-27-generic

Comment: From there I clicked on the amd64 link which too me to http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/linux-image-3.13.0-27-generic/download where I was FINALLY able to download the deb package.  I repeated the same process to fetch the headers from http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/linux-headers-3.13.0-27
Once I had both deb packages, I installed using "sudo dpkg -i *.deb"
The install was successful, I rebooted into the new kernel and discovered I had no wireless connectivity. When I did this entire process with the 3.13.0-29 kernel I still had wireless so I'm not sure what is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing several drivers including wireless drivers because you need to also install:

```
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-27-generic
```

from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/kernel/) .

Comment: EUREKA!  That fixed it.  I also found the directions to "pin" that kernel so that it won't get updated again too.  Thanks for your help.