# WiFi not working depending on kernel choice at start

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, kernel

I've tried to search on forums but I'm not able to find a clear solution to this problem.

I have installed 16.04 in my laptop, and WiFi was working well until an automatic upgrade. On Grub the actual version I'm running is 4.8.0-52-generic

Succesive upgrades (4.8.0-56, 4.8.0-58 and so...) not activates WiFi and I don't know how to activate it.

I'm thinking on downgrade until .52 and then try to upgrade directly to latest version, but I'm so disoriented, what I have to do? Downgrade or patch?

The output of `sudo lshw -C network` is:

```
*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: enp2s0
   version: 10
   serial: 1c:b7:2c:a2:99:d9
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:48 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:a3204000-a3204fff memory:a3200000-a3203fff
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlp3s0f0
   version: 00
   serial: 40:b8:9a:4f:c8:65
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt7630e driverversion=4.8.0-52-generic firmware=112.3 ip=192.168.43.48 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:19 memory:a3100000-a31fffff
```

Thanks for your help,

Comment: The situation is a bit different (downgrade instead of upgrade) but maybe [this answer to a similar question](https://askubuntu.com/a/489269/326100) helps (TL;DR: install `linux-image-extra-XXXX-generic`)

Comment: @luator I'll try and tell you, thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

The only way for you to have the driver *mt7630e* working in 4.8.0-52 is that you compiled the driver from source code. You compiled it for the currently running kernel only; that is xx-52. Please reboot and select the latest kernel version you have available and re-compile:

```
cd Downloads/MT7630E
```

...or wherever you downloaded the files,

```
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe mt7630e
```

Your wireless should now be working.

Whenever Update Manager offers a later kernel version, after the requested reboot, repeat the process.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it doesn't worked at all. To work properly with wifi (networks in general) I still have to start with a previous kernel version. I'll try to reinstall complete system some day, I think. Thanks again!