# Is it possible to downgrade 11.10 kernel version to 2.6?

Tags: 11.10, 10.10, kernel

Is it possible to downgrade the kernel (oneiric) to the version used by 10.10?

Comment: maybe - why dont you give it a try and let us know what you find out - http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

Comment: @fossfreedom I'd not recommend the mainline kernel for downgrading.

Comment: hence my "maybe" - compile or find the three kernel debs from the maverick repo probably...

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to downgrade?  At best downgrading will be a temporary solution, since no future version of Ubuntu is going to revert to 2.6.x kernels.  If there is a particular problem you are having, there might be a solution that works with current versions.

Comment: Temporary as I just want to avoid the overheating problem in Kernel 3.0 and above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing that your mean reason is overheating, I'd suggest installing Precise Pangolin A1.
It is the current development version, but seeing it's for an LTS version it will mainly see bug fixes and ironing out the flaws. I've heard from reliable people that the A1 (or Alpha 1) is seeing great improvements in terms of power management.
You can also check out this Google-search: [power management ubuntu 12.04](http://www.google.nl/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=power%20management%20ubuntu%2012.04)

Comment: I'd just install the precise kernel not the WHOLE untested OS.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade: [How to downgrade the Kernel on 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71139/how-to-downgrade-the-kernel-on-11-10)

Note: At here, with the 10.10 kernel, network connection wasn't working.

Upgrade: [How can I upgrade kernel to 3.1?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72714/how-can-i-upgrade-kernel-to-3-1)

Note: The Precise kernel is now 3.2.

More of the 12.04: https://askubuntu.com/questions/81902/when-will-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin-be-released