# I updated yesterday 15.6.2012 and now I cant boot with 3.2.0-25 I have to enter with 3.2.0-24

Tags: 12.04, updates, boot-failure

I updated yesterday 15.6.2012 and now I cant boot with 3.2.0-25 I have to enter with 3.2.0-24.

Can anyone help?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

Could you be more specific about how you did it? Did you update it manually or using Update Manager?

Have a look at this if you don't know how to upgrade kernel: [How can I upgrade kernel to 3.1?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72714/how-can-i-upgrade-kernel-to-3-1)

The process is pretty much same even in this case. Just remember to use the kernel images provided by Ubuntu (for that particular version) here: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

To remove that obsolete kernel installation:

Go to Synaptic and select the linux kernel headers and image of the kernel version which is not working and mark them for removal and apply changes. Then in the terminal run
    update-grub to write changes to grub.

Hope you understand it!

Comment: I used the update manager. I went to synaptic and marked the linux kernel headers for reinstall, but its still not working, the pc reboots. Linux its a bit complicated for me, I've been using it for 6 months.

Comment: That's odd... I suggest you to remove (not re-install) the broken kernel packages using synaptic (3.2.0.25 in this case) and run update-grub in terminal. Now, restart and GRUB will show you only the working version. After booting, once again try kernel upgrade (follow instructions about how to do it in the above questions - so that you won't land into trouble again). If the installation is successful (which it will be), boot into new kernel and remove old kernel (like you did using synaptic) and you will be set! Hope it works for you... ;)